# matplotlib: pie chart , variable pctdistance

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I want to be able to position each  percentage value at different distance from the center, but pctdistance needs to be a single value.

For my case pctdistance should be a list that would contain generated distances (generated by a range).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig =plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax11 = fig.add_subplot(111)
# Data to plot
labels = 'Python', 'C++', 'Ruby', 'Java'
sizes = [215, 130, 245, 2000]
colors = ['gold', 'yellowgreen', 'lightcoral', 'lightskyblue']
explode = (0.1, 0, 0, 0)  # explode 1st slice

# Plot
w,l,p = ax11.pie(sizes,  labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=140, pctdistance=0.8, radius = 0.5)
[t.set_rotation(0) for t in p]
[t.set_fontsize(50) for t in p]
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

What I have:
[image]
What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `pie` function does not take lists or arrays as input for the `pctdistance` argument.

You may position the texts manually using a predefined list of `pctdistances`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig =plt.figure(figsize = (4,4))
ax11 = fig.add_subplot(111)
# Data to plot
labels = 'Python', 'C++', 'Ruby', 'Java'
sizes = [215, 130, 245, 2000]
colors = ['gold', 'yellowgreen', 'lightcoral', 'lightskyblue']

# Plot
w,l,p = ax11.pie(sizes,  labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=140, pctdistance=1, radius = 0.5)

pctdists = [.8, .5, .4, .2]

for t,d in zip(p, pctdists):
    xi,yi = t.get_position()
    ri = np.sqrt(xi**2+yi**2)
    phi = np.arctan2(yi,xi)
    x = d*ri*np.cos(phi)
    y = d*ri*np.sin(phi)
    t.set_position((x,y))

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before trying something more difficult, it is worth optimizing the parameters of the plot. Here is what you can get with an appropriate choice of font size and pctdistance and including explode:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig =plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax11 = fig.add_subplot(111)
# Data to plot
sizes = [215, 130, 245, 2000]
labels = 'Python', 'C++', 'Ruby', 'Java'
colors = ['gold', 'yellowgreen', 'lightcoral', 'lightskyblue']
explode = (0.1, 0, 0, 0)  # explode 1st slice

# Plot
w,l,p = ax11.pie(sizes,  labels=labels, colors=colors,
        autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=140, pctdistance=0.65, radius = 1, explode=explode)
[t.set_rotation(0) for t in p]
[t.set_fontsize(25) for t in p]
[t.set_fontsize(25) for t in l]
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is also something to keep in mind to try when one has individual pies.

Comment: You are very welcome! I felt compelled to post this answer and am glad it has been received well.